# Can we get a warning popup if an answer contains the word "late" or "old"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, late-answers

There are so many answers where people put fluff saying "I know this answer is really late but"...

Here are five answers with the word "late" in the last ***five hours*** where it *didn't* already get edited out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316620/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315230/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314596/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311872/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311165/1768232

Here are ones with the word "old" from *just the last **two hours***

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316409/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316118/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315675/1768232 (this one is probably flaggable tbh)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315329/1768232
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314862/1768232

Some caveats:

It needs to be the complete word, for some obvious reasons:

- Use version blah blah or **later**
- Blah bla may be **related**
- Copy blah into your **folder**
- Are you on an **older** version of blah.

Also, the word should be allowed if it's inside backticks or code blocks, or if the post actually is new, e.g. must be **at least 1 month old before this check is done.**

Also, I **don't think it should actually prevent the post from getting posted,** I'm asking specifically for the "yellow" warning popup, saying something along the lines of (I'm interested in suggestions to improve this text):

> Don't include extra text in your answer such as "I know this is a late answer". Just state your answer simply, clearly, and completely.

Comment: In my point of view, we should just edit these out. If we start to popup for every not recomended word usage, the post answer page will be a little mess...
Also, they won't read.

Comment: @Malavos We should edit them out, but it would be nice if the system taught people they were doing wrong stuff.

Comment: Do we currently warn for "thanks", or unacceptable language? This is more of the same, no?

Comment: What if late or old are variable names?

Comment: @NathanOliver That, or they just qualify other words that are key elements of the answer (i.e. not noise): "the event is going to fire *late*", "the *old* data won't be accessible anymore", etc. I'm sure I've got many uses of "old" and "late" in my answers like in these examples.

Comment: @Louis It's just a warning. You can still submit the post.

Comment: Yes, but it's a warning that's likely to be unwarranted in many cases, which means it'll be an annoyance and people will learn to ignore it.

Comment: It might be better to expand the ["Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings." section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) with an explanation of what "noise" is and how to avoid it when creating posts.

Comment: @BSMP People are very unlikely to read that. They *might* read an in your face warning.

Comment: This will pick up too many valid cases of those words to make this useful. I'm declining this for the time-being.

Comment: Let's not add more clutter. We need to find another way to improve on how users make questions - not insert more information onto user screens while posting - they will simply not read it. Your intent is noble, but it lacks the laziness that we have as users.

Comment: @bluefeet Okay thanks for the response

Comment: @bluefeet In my answer I looked into the false positive rate. If we search for "late" and "old" in the first 100 characters of answers on questions that are at least a month old, then you will flag about 17 answers that start with fluff for every non-fluff answer flagged.

Comment: @josilber I'm sticking with a decline on this.  I'm not seeing much of a benefit here and adding a popup will only bring noise to users.

Comment: *People are very unlikely to read that.* - Yes, but they're *supposed* to be reading those sections of the Help Center. Putting it there will give folks editing noise out of posts something to point to when explaining their edits. So instead of [long rambly explanation of why that text is bad], you'd use "this text is considered noise, see [help/behavior]". The notice only gets shown on posts & to users who need to see it.

Answer (score 4):

"Late" and "old" are just words in our language - they could be used in *all sorts* of legitimate scenarios. So this would just be an annoyance to fix a small issue which can be done through moderating - there are plenty of us.

While it's likely rare a user won't post because of the pop-up warning, I'm against annoying any user who is posting a decent post to be "warned" about using a legitimate word.

Some possible legitimate reasons to use "late":

1. Late binding
2. Late rendering
3. Late email from server
4. Late response
5. Late notification
6. Late server time

Some possible legitimate reasons to use "old":

1. Old code
2. Old method
3. Old server
4. Old style
5. Old version
6. Old commit
7. Old data

It's likely rare this is an issue worth bothering to automate, especially taking into account users who'd ignore the warning message and post anyway, you just annoy many users with legitimate reasons than you do solve problems.

---

### Edit

Notes:

1. Yes, it's arguably "fluff" and legitimate to be edited out
2. There are too many false positives (as per above list + more)
3. False positives will likely annoy users, and a professional site
   should not frustrate it's users when they are doing *normal* things
4. We should not (never) annoy users when the benefits are only to
   remove a little bit of (arguably) "harmless fluff" - it's not like
   we're battling profanities or long sentences of waffle
5. Their answer will bump to the front page for all to see, and their
   stating "Bit late but" they're just giving a nod to others that they
   recognised the question is old and already answered, but they feel
   they have something additional to add.
6. Just manually edit such things, there's no need for warnings as it's
   not a *major* issue (based on it being a few words and not
   profanities etc, *not* based on frequency)

[Searching for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%22late%20binding%22%20is%3Aanswer) `"late binding" is:answer` returns 1,751 results
That's *one* search with *one* legitimate use!

Consider:

**They're essentially stating:**

> I know the question is old and already answered, but I have something
>   to add I feel would be beneficial to others, and maybe even the OP,
>   your variable blah etc

**By doing:**

> Late answer, but your variable blah etc

That doesn't necessarily make it "acceptable" but there is merit in why they write it (as per point 5 above).

---

To argue this feature request is legitimate and would resolve the issue, you need stats (yourself or someone else) to show how much of a problem this actually is from some form of *accurate and useful* data showing legitimate use verses illegitimate use (not first 100 words from one month only as this is weak).

Comment: That example you gave is bad and needs fast culling (it may be marginally useful immediately posted as a comment), otherwise a good answer.

Comment: 1. With the example you gave, you don't need that lead in, it's fluff. 2. In principle, I agree with you; however, in practice, these examples you give are the vast *minority*.

Comment: Also, my list of potentials are valid, and eg "late binding" quite well used - see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22late%22

Comment: See @josilber's answer.

Comment: @durron597 See my comment on their answer.

Comment: Well, 12% false positives isn't really bad for a warning. The harm they cause doesn't justify anything above *maybe* 1% though.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** The proposed filter will find roughly 17 posts beginning with fluff for every non-fluff post it catches.

I think the biggest challenge with this sort of a warning would be false positives -- posts with "late" or "old" used in appropriate ways triggering the warning. In the comments on your question, @bluefeet cites this as the reason for the [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined). Obviously we can all imagine many legitimate uses of the words "late" and "old" in an answer, so the key question is whether we would mostly be catching fluff with the filter you propose or whether we would mostly be catching legitimate uses of "late" and "old". This is a question that can only be addressed with data.

To answer this question, I searched the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for recent answers (all were from July 2015) created at least one month after the associated question was created with the word "old" or "late" in the first 100 characters using the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 SUBSTRING(a.Body, 1, 100), a.Id, q.Id, a.CreationDate, q.CreationDate
FROM Posts a INNER JOIN Posts q on a.ParentId=q.Id
WHERE a.PostTypeId=2
  AND q.PostTypeId=1
  AND DATEDIFF(day, q.CreationDate, a.CreationDate) > 30
  AND Year(a.CreationDate)=2015
  AND (Substring(a.Body, 1, 100) LIKE '% late %' OR
       Substring(a.Body, 1, 100) LIKE '% old %');
```

I then manually labeled the first 200 answers based on whether they had fluff in the beginning mentioning that this was an answer to an old question. In total 189 of the 200 were fluff, meaning 94.5% of posts flagged were true positives and the remainder were false positives. Put another way, 17 fluff posts would get a warning for every non-fluff post that got a warning.

Whether or not this flagging rate is acceptable is a matter of opinion, but it seems to me that limiting to late answers and searching for the words "late" or "old" in the first 100 characters of the answer yields far more true positives than false positives (about 17 times as many).

#### False Positives

For those interested, here are the false positives I encountered: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280636) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289374) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31292714) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324115) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31329181) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31340580) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31348351) [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372954) [9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386626) [10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397153) [11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31400650)

Comment: This is what I'm saying, there's vastly more true positives than false positives here.

Comment: Narrowing this down to one month and only the first 100 characters is a really poor example. What if there are many more uses of the word "late" or "old" throughout the rest of some of the posts? That would be more false positives. What if July is a bad month for them? This is like me going out into the street and asking 10 random people if they broke a bone in 2014, and 1 person saying yes, and so I state "1 in 10 people break a bone".

Comment: @James of course, when you search by relevance you get answers with many occurrences of the word, which is a natural false positive selector.

Comment: @durron597 My point is not percentage false positives to legitimate uses, as that would take a mammoth query, time, and likely never 100% accurate without some manual reading etc. It's more about showing examples of legitimate uses. That aside - why wouldn't it also return "I know my answer is late"? Incidentally searching for "I know my answer is late" and "I know this answer is late" returns 34 results in total

Comment: [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358179) probably closer models the OPs proposal, looking at the initial revision and listing the newest matches. Doesn't seem to change the final conclusion though.

Comment: Ok, so my next argument, is it even worth it? One of the results from the query link @Deduplicator gave is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32213391/2632129 is this really worth an automated script which will mostly bother people from false positives and possibly tidy up some "trivial" things? That answer states "It's an old question, but here is an alternative:" I mean, it's hardly a major issue is it? In fact, in longer posts some people might decline for edit being too trivial. (FYI we get notifications if you reply in a certain time period even without the ping :))

Comment: @James you will never convince me that this is not a real problem. I edit noise out like this all the time (and I'm correct to do so). Bluefeet's argument seems to me to be that this is not the best solution to this problem, which has merit. But whether the problem exists? It definitely does. 5 true positives on "old" in the two hours prior to me posting the original question...

Comment: Yes the problem exists, but this will return more false positives than it will fix. I'm not arguing there is no problem, I'm arguing there are legitimate uses of the word. And the stats here in this answer are pointless. We should never annoy many users to fix basic issues. If we were talking about profanities or long sentences of waffle maybe, but it's not exactly a major issue having "I'm a bit late but...". Not when you just annoy **many** people!

Comment: @James `This will return more false positives than it will fix.` Do you have some evidence for that? Note that the whole point of my answer was to bring data into the discussion. `The stats here in this answer are pointless` -- is this coming from your fear that there are wild swings in the use of the words "late" and "old" through time? I find that unlikely, though I suppose I could take a random sample through time... `Not when you just annoy many people!` From my query, you would annoy about one person per day with a false positive warning, so perhaps not such a big deal?

Comment: Ok, I retract "more than will fix" but 1) Your stats are not accurate or really useful, seems you are biased(?); 2) The entire point is **there are legitimate uses** so *you* (or OP) need to produce stats which show total legitimate vs illegitimate to argue if the proposal is worth it or not. As it stands, as per my answer, there are *too many legitimate* uses to go ahead with this. Prove otherwise - even taking *one* legitimate use "late binding" is used **many** times

Comment: @James: Took a closer look at the newest few my query returns. And it's actually a real problem.

Comment: @James the whole point of this answer (as captured by the tl;dr line at the beginning) was to compare the number of legitimate versus illegitimate uses of the filter, so I was trying to do exactly the analysis task you say is needed. If you want to see the raw data, I shared it [here](http://pastebin.com/z81va6CY). As you can see, the vast majority of things picked up by the filter start with fluff.

Comment: @durron597 Yes, the problem _might_ have merit but we have bigger problems on the site to try and tackle. This is peanuts and just generates noise to users.

Comment: @james and josilber: Posted my own analysis using my own enhanced search using initial body to eliminate bias through edits, and over the latest examples to minimize biase through deletions.

Comment: @bluefeet You've already convinced me on those grounds. I appreciate that others have chosen to pick up my standard where I have dropped it, but I agree with you this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at the newest ones which fit the criteria, to avoid many having already be dealt with through community moderation.
I used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358179?maxposts=25):

```sql
select top ##maxposts:int?1000## substring(ph.text, 1, 100), a.id [Post Link]
, q.id, a.creationdate, q.creationdate
from posts a
join posts q on q.id=a.parentid
join posthistory ph on ph.postid=a.id and ph.posthistorytypeid=2
where datediff(d, q.creationdate, a.creationdate) > 30
  and (substring(ph.text, 1, 100) like '% late %'
    or substring(ph.text, 1, 100) like '% old %')
order by a.creationdate desc
```

Analyzation of the latest 25 samples caught:

- false positives: 3

  - minmal answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32213531) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32205307)
  - good answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201387)
- true positives 22:

  - link-only: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206653) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32199728) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193678)
  - disclaimer "old": [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32213391) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32212527) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210367) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210349) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208909) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202651) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32200779) [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197664) [9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191614) [10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32188794)
  - disclaimer "late": [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211716) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211534) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206497) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201820) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32200988) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198973) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198459) [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190961) [9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190503)

Though aside from those where it indicated deeper trouble (~12%), it wasn't very intrusive, so few thought it worthwhile to edit it out.

Comment: "few thought it worthwhile to edit it out" On a longish answer, a suggested edit for removing "A late answer but" would often be rejected for being no improvement (too trivial). That's not saying "it's not a problem" but is saying "it's not a major problem it being in an answer".